# Macro VBA with Excel to insert/store image to MSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a folder with images (person photo) that need to be used in reporting and I want to save them in a SQL Server table. I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have created a table. I am neither an Admin(sa/dbo) nor I have permissions to use the `BULK` statement. I searched many sites but found none so far without `BULK` statement.

I have a userform developed in excel and using VBA to execute the insert query image to connect to sql with SSIS (if I am an admin the insert blob query executed successfully from my workstation) however if I am neither admin(sa/dbo) I tried using other workstation cause I have my sql server set up to allow access remotedly using tcp and open port 443. It fails to insert

Most people suggested using :

```
INSERT INTO PersonImage

SELECT * FROM 

OPENROWSET(BULK "Imagepath", SINGLE_BLOB) AS image
```

I cannot use this or any statement with `BULK` in it. Could anyone of you suggest a way arround to load these images into the table with out using `BULK` `INSERT` statement?

Your help is appreciated!

Thanks and Regards